# Website a Broken link an google webmaster tools is giving me an error

Tags: google, google-search-console

Hi my website is only a month old but I have paid to have traffic to my site so I don't know if maybe that is the problem. I have an error in webmaster tools for a url link `http://www.example.com/null.html`? I never made that page so as you can understand I was a tad confused. Does anyone have any insight as to what I should do next an if I should cancel my paid traffic with the company in question or if that is normal.

Comment: @w3dk replacing the actual link with www.example.com is appreciated, but the question becomes unclear because there's no way to know what's the cause. Your answer probably seems useful, but as of current it looks like just a guess, because www.example.com doesn't have that code. Probably you can salvage this question to make your answer more meaningful.

Comment: @AndrewT. To be honest, I'm not sure that this question is salvageable - any bug finding questions that are specific to one website (and that requires a link to that website) are generally considered off-topic anyway. (Any website link would become stale anyway once the bug is fixed.) Invalid internal links are at least covered in the duplicate question/answer (but the OP had already seen that question before posting here). And yes, my answer could be improved - I'll try to improve it.

Comment: Hi I am very appricated for the answers. Thank you w3dk & Andrew T, John conde. Yes It looks to be the banner, when you click on it, it takes me to 404. How can i resolve the issue or should I change the banner ? Thank YOU For The Answer About Traffic Aswell I'm Very Great Full.

Comment: Is it a internal or external link? If it is external, did you contacted the webmaster?

Answer (score 0):

If Google Search Console (formerly Webmaster Tools) is reporting a 404, then you can usually drill down on the link in the report to find where the URL is being linked from. This will give a big clue as to the source of the problem.

The first thing to check are your internal links. A quick search for "null.html" in the page source of your homepage reveals that your banner is wrapped in an anchor that is linking to `/null.html`. This is on *every page*, so yes, Google will report a lot of 404s if this link is invalid.

```
<a href="/null.html" title="fat burning exercises" target="_self">
<img id="zpBannerBg" class=""style="opacity: 1;"src="/theme/images/bannerimage.png"  width="960px" onload="fnSetBannerImg(this,960,360)" />
</a>
```

> I have paid to have traffic to my site

This is not the cause of the problem (although invalid inbound links are also obviously a common source of 404s). But any "paid for" traffic (through advertising / marketing / promotion) needs to be specically targetted for it to have any worth?

Comment: I don't get it. The banner links to that url does it ?? How can I resolve that ? An yes I paid for traffic lol should I not have lol.

Comment: Is there anyway I can stop the banner from doing that or should I just replace it with an alter text. That Banner Came Standard With Thw Website. And the company I have paid to have traffi with is "Internet traffic service"

Comment: "How can I resolve that?" - Remove the HTML anchor if you have no meaningful page for the banner to link to. Although exactly how you do that may be dependent on the CMS/templating engine you are using. I'm not really sure of the benefits of "paying for traffic" through the service you mention. If it's untargeted or bot traffic then it's next to useless. I've updated my answer.